# Integral of a linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose I know that $f: \mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^N$ is the gradient function of $g:\mathbb{R}^N\to \mathbb{R}$, that is $\nabla_x g(x) = f(x)$.

I also know that $f:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^N$ is a linear function, so I am assuming $f(x) = Ax + b$ for some matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ and a vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^N$.

I would now like to find the function $g$. For this reason I compute the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} f(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} (Ax + b) dx = ?
$$

Comment: I don't think this makes sense. $f:R^N\to R$ don't have antiderivatives because the derivative of a function $R^N\to R$ would be a function $R^N\to R^N$ (unless N=1, because that's when both cases coincide)

Comment: @NinadMunshi what would be the correct expression for this? The thing is I know that $f(x) = \nabla_x g(x)$ for some function $g:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$, I just need to find the function $g(x)$.

Comment: What you're asking for is impossible and whoever told you that is mistaken. fcannot be the gradient of some function because the gradient would be a vector. If you want any more proof that what you've written down is impossible, the left hand side is a vector but the right hand side is a scalar plus a vector plus a scalar.

Comment: @NinadMunshi true.. then I must have messed up the notation. Give me a second

Comment: @Physics_Student I saw your question from last night and found your notation confusing. Do you mean that the operator $\nabla_x := \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$? And then is the vector $x$ actually something like $[x,y,z,w,...]$?

Comment: @vb628 I have edited the question, I hope it makes a bit more sense now..

Comment: @NinadMunshi Okay I have found were my notation was wrong!

Comment: Gotcha! So the antiderivative still will not exist in general (f will not be conservative) unless A is a symmetric matrix.

Comment: @Physics_Student I'm drumming up an answer that might be satisfactory and give you what you want to know.

Comment: @NinadMunshi would you mind showing me why it would not exist in general and what you mean by conservative?

Comment: @vb628 thank you so much!

Comment: @Physics_Student I'm adding conservative fields to my answer. Basically, a vector field is conservative iff it can be written as the integral of a scalar function.

Comment: Technically, this is not a linear function but an affine one.

Comment: Due to the term $b$, the integral will diverge over $\mathbb R^N$.

Comment: @Yves exactly but the gradient also won't even be affine in general.

Comment: @vb628: this is what the OP claims.

Comment: You do not want to integrate over $\Bbb R^N$. Review the process of finding a potential function by integrating along line segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things right off the bat, $f:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^N$ can't quite be put in the form you desire because it is not in general linear/affine. You will find that if it is the gradient of a scalar function, it will look more like this

$$ \nabla{g}(x) = f(x) = \vec{b}(x) $$ where $b$ is usually thought of as  a row.

Consider some scalar function $V:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. The "gradient" of $V$ can be expressed by the differential 1-form

$$ dV = \sum_k  \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x^k} dx^k $$

where we can integrate

$$ \Delta V = \int_\gamma dV = \int_\gamma \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}dx + \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial y}dy + \cdots $$ over some curve $\gamma$. It is important to note that the form above is the most natural differential form of the scalar field $V$ and it is naturally integrated over a specific path through space. You may have seen the notation in physics/vector calculus that

$$ \Delta V = \int_\gamma \nabla V \cdot \vec{ds} $$ which turns out to be the "vector from" of $dV$ rather than the 1-form.

We can integrate a vector field $\vec{G}$ over a curve in the same way by writing

$$\int_\gamma \vec{G} \cdot \vec{ds}$$ but it is not always as "nice" as integrating a field $\vec{F} = \nabla V$.

Consider a family of parametric curves $\gamma_k(t)$ where $\gamma_k(0) = p$ and $\gamma_k(1) = q$ for some points $p$ and $q$. Clearly the choice of path is not unique as the only restrictions are the starting and ending points. If we integrate our function $\vec{F}$ that is the gradient of a scalar function, we a guaranteed that

$$ \int_{\gamma_1} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{ds} =\int_{\gamma_2} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{ds} = V(q) - V(p)$$

independent of the choice of $\gamma$ so long as we don't run into any discontinuities. We call such a vector function a "conservative function" (think classical gravitation or classical E&M). In this sense, we can "undo" the gradient $\vec{F}$ of a scalar function and recover information about the underlying "potential function" $V$.

If some function $\vec{G}$ is not the gradient of a scalar potential, then the above-mentioned integral is not conservative, a.k.a. it is pathway dependent. It is sufficient to show that

$$ \int_{\gamma_1} \vec{G} \cdot \vec{ds} \neq\int_{\gamma_2} \vec{G} \cdot \vec{ds} $$

for sufficiently differentiable paths in order to prove that $\vec{G}$ is not conservative.

Usually we compute a line integral by finding what is known as the "pull-back"

$$ \int_{\gamma} \vec{G} \cdot \vec{ds} =\int_{\gamma(t)} \bigg(\sum_k G_k \dfrac{dx^k}{dt} \bigg) dt $$

where $\vec{x}'(t) = \gamma'(t)$.

One big caveat: a few things I said are really only completely correct in cartesian coordinates but the general methodology is fairly easy to generalize.

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic polynomial

$$\frac12x^TAx+b^Tx+c$$ has the gradient $$Ax+b.$$

Comment: Only if $A$ is symmetric! Otherwise you would take the symmetric part.

Comment: @NinadMunshi: yes, $A$ symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

The function $Ax+b$ is not linear!

A linear function $f:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^M$ must satisfy

$c_1 f(v) + c_2 f(w) = f(c_1 v + c_2 w)$.

I think you want $f(x) = A x.$